# How do I use the 'values' function of the hash package with unclassing the elements?

Tags: r

When I try and extract the values from a hash, using the `values` function they lose their class:

```
> h <- hash( c('a','b'), Sys.time() )
> h
<hash> containing 2 key-value pair(s).
  a : 2014-02-02 10:41:43
  b : 2014-02-02 10:41:43

> values( h )
           a          b 
  1391366503 1391366503 

> class( values(h) )
[1] "numeric"
```

But they are still the correct class within the hash:

```
> class( h$a )
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
 > class( h$b )
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

How can I recover the values and preserve their class?

Comment: Perhaps `values(h, simplify = F)` is helpful? I ended here reading through `?values`. And something like `do.call(c, values(h, simplify = F))` to lose the `list`.

Comment: Thanks that's it.  Then all you need to do is collect the results with `Reduce` or `c`.  If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?hash::values` we note that there is a `...` argument(s) passed to `sapply`. `sapply` then, with its "simplify" argument set to `TRUE` by default, calls `simplify2array` where the date format is changed to a "numeric" in this line `...as.vector(unlist(x, recursive = FALSE))...`.

An example:

```
xx = c(Sys.time() + 1:3)
xx
#[1] "2014-02-02 21:54:01 EET" "2014-02-02 21:54:02 EET" "2014-02-02 21:54:03 EET"
sapply(xx, I)
#[1] 1391370842 1391370843 1391370844
sapply(xx, I, simplify = F)
#[[1]]
#[1] "2014-02-02 21:54:01 EET"    
#[[2]]
#[1] "2014-02-02 21:54:02 EET"    
#[[3]]
#[1] "2014-02-02 21:54:03 EET"

as.vector(xx)
#[1] 1391370842 1391370843 1391370844
typeof(xx)  #i.e. how "Date" class is stored internally
#[1] "double"
class(xx)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
mode(xx)
#[1] "numeric"
```

And to answer the question, a solution could be:

```
do.call(c, sapply(xx, I, simplify = F))
#[1] "2014-02-02 21:57:39 EET" "2014-02-02 21:57:40 EET" "2014-02-02 21:57:41 EET"
```

or, as you suggested:

```
Reduce(c, sapply(xx, I, simplify = F))
#[1] "2014-02-02 21:57:39 EET" "2014-02-02 21:57:40 EET" "2014-02-02 21:57:41 EET"

Reduce(c, values(h, simplify = F))
#[1] "2014-02-02 22:00:09 EET" "2014-02-02 22:00:09 EET"
```